# Webpack generating child chunks for dynamic imported modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-4, react-loadable

I'm using [react-loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable) to dynamically import the route component, webpack is generating the chunk file but the issue is that the child modules that are imported inside the dynamically imported component is also generated in a separate chunk file. So it's generating multiple chunk files. I tried `/* webpackChunkName: "lazyComponent" */` but it didn't worked

Comment: check `commons-chunk-plugin` https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin if it can help

Comment: Also tried with https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/ (split-chunks-pulgin) but still generating multiple files